# Google App Engine Java Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just started off with Google App Engine 1.6.4 in Eclipse Indigo a couple of days ago and I face a problem with the back end.

Whenever I try to use a servlet or a JSP, I get this annoying

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/msamogh/MyServlet : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I tried changing my JRE to Java 6, but the error still remains. Does anyone know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

The *major.minor* version 51.0 seems to indicate that your classes are compiled using Java 7. Please make sure that the following are done:

- Start Eclipse using a Java 6 JDK.
- Set the default JVM in Eclipse to a Java 6 JDK.
- Set the default and/or project compiler settings to use *1.6* target.

In general, you need to make sure that your runtime JRE is able to understand your compiled code. If you try to run code compiled for *1.7* on a *1.6* JRE, you will get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

What is your output when you do  `java -version`? This will tell you what version the running JVM is.

The Unsupported `major.minor version 51.0 error` could mean:

app  is running on a lower Java version then the one used to compile it

Try adding a SYSTEM VARIABLE that looks like this: `JRE_HOME = C:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\JRE7` or `JRE6` shipped with the JDK 1.7 or later package with which you compiled it.